# Eliminar elementos mayores a una longitudde una lista en python

Tags: python, lista, while

```
tallas = ['Selecciona tu talla', '35 ½', '36', '36 ½', '37 ½', '38', '38 ½', '39', '40', '40 ½', '41', '42', '42 ½', '43', '44', '44 ½', 'Nuevo y sin estrenar', 'Garantía de autenticidad al 100 %', 'Realizamos envíos por Postnl, UPS y DHL Express', 'Devoluciones gratuitas, periodo de reflexión de 30 días']

j = 0
while j < len(tallas):
    if len(tallas[j]) > 4:   
        tallas.pop(j)
        j += 1
    else:
        j += 1

print("Tallas: ", tallas)

#salida: Tallas:  ['35 ½', '36', '36 ½', '37 ½', '38', '38 ½', '39', '40', '40 ½', '41', '42', '42 ½', '43', '44', '44 ½', 'Garantía de autenticidad al 100 %', 'Devoluciones gratuitas, periodo de reflexión de 30 días']
```

De la lista `tallas` quiero eliminar todo lo que no son tallas, entonces lo he intentado con el bucle `while` que he creado usando `pop()` en los elementos con mas de 4 de longitud usando `len()` para comprobarlo, pero solo elimina algunos de los elementos, no entiendo lo que pasa. No entiendo por que quedan esos 2 strings al final de la lista.

Answer (score 1):

El error es que avanzas el indice `j` luego de eliminar un elemento con `pop`. El índice no debería avanzar, pues ahora un nuevo elemento no examinado ocupa esa posición.

En todo caso, es pésima práctica alterar una lista mientras la recorres, pues conduce a todo tipo de errores, como éste.

La buena práctica es crear una nueva lista:

```
salida = []
for elemento in tallas:
    if len(elemento) <= 4:
        salida.append(elemento)
```

Esto es mucho más claro: recorres la lista sin alterarla ni cambiarla, copiando sólo los elementos que te interesan.

Copiar una lista es una operación barata en Python, pues no se copian los elementos mismos, sólo sus referencias (punteros).

#### Demo

```
tallas = ['Selecciona tu talla', '35 ½', '36', '36 ½', '37 ½', '38', '38 ½', '39', '40', '40 ½', '41', '42', '42 ½', '43', '44', '44 ½', 'Nuevo y sin estrenar', 'Garantía de autenticidad al 100 %', 'Realizamos envíos por Postnl, UPS y DHL Express', 'Devoluciones gratuitas, periodo de reflexión de 30 días']

salida = []
for elemento in tallas:
    if len(elemento) <= 4:
        salida.append(elemento)

print("Tallas: ", salida)
```

produce:

```
Tallas:  ['35 ½', '36', '36 ½', '37 ½', '38', '38 ½', '39', '40', '40 ½', '41', '42', '42 ½', '43', '44', '44 ½']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Esto debería solucionarlo:

```
tallas = [x for x in tallas if len(x) <= 4]
print("Tallas: ", tallas)
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y explicar por que tu idea soluciona el problema por favor? De ese modo aumentarás la calidad de tu respuesta, será mejor recibida y tanto el OP como otras personas con el mismo problema podrían aprender algo nuevo. Además Stack Overflow no es un repositorio de código.